# Spark Scala: mapPartitions in this use case

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was reading a lot about the differences between map and mapPartitions. Still I have some doubts. 
The thing is after reading I decided to change the `map` functions for `mapPartitions` in my code because apparently `mapPartitions` is faster than `map`.

My question is about to be sure if my decision is right in scenarios like the following (*comments show the previous code*):

```
val reducedRdd = rdd.mapPartitions(partition => partition.map(r => (r.id, r)))
//val reducedRdd = rdd.map(r => (r.id, r))
.reduceByKey((r1, r2) => r1.combineElem(r2))
// .map(e => e._2)
.mapPartitions(partition => partition.map(e => e._2))
```

I am thinking it right? Thanks!

Comment: I doubt in this case `mapPartitions` would be faster _(but you should always profile yourself)_. I would expect it to be faster if you need to chain multiple operations on each partition, like `partition.map(...).filter(...).map(...)`. Also, remember that because each partition is an **iterator** it is a mutable object, thus more unsafe that normal `map`, so, I would not use it, unless you can measure a real performance improvement.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, mapPartitions should not make any difference.

> mapPartitions vs map

mapPartitions is useful when we have some common computation which we want to do for each partition. Example -

```
rdd.mapPartitions{
  partition => 
    val complicatedRowConverter = <SOME-COSTLY-COMPUTATION>
    partition.map {
      row => (row.id, complicatedRowConverter(row) )
    }
}
```

In above example, we are creating a `complicatedRowConverter` function which is dervived from some costly computation. This function will be same for entire 
 RDD partition and we don't need recreate it again and again. The other way to do same thing can be -

```
rdd.map { row => 
      val complicatedRowConverter = <SOME-COSTLY-COMPUTATION>
      (row.id, complicatedRowConverter(row) )
    }
}
```

This will be slow because we are unnecessarily running this statement for every row - `val complicatedRowConverter = <SOME-COSTLY-COMPUTATION>`.

In your case, you don't have any precomputation or anything else for each partition. In the mapPartition, you are simply iterating over each row and mapping it to `(row.id, row)`.

So mapPartition here won't benefit and you can use simple map.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr `mapPartitions` will be fast in this case.

## Why

consider a function

```
def someFunc(row): row {
  // do some processing on row
  // return new row
}
```

Say we are processing 1million records

#### map

We will end up calling the `someFunc` 1 million.
There are bascally 1m virtual function call and other kernel data structures created for the processing

#### mapPartition

we would write this as

```
mapPartition { partIter =>
  partIter.map {
    // do some processing on row
    // return new row
  }
}
```

No virual functions, context switch here.

Hence `mapPartitions` will be faster.

Also, like mentioned in the @moriarity007's answer, we also need to factor in the object creation overhead involved with the operation, when deciding between the operator to use.

Also, I would recommend using the dataframe transforms and actions to do processing, where the compute can be even faster, since Spark catalyst optimizes your code and also take advantage of code generation.